# Sorting 2D Int Array in Java without comparator using helper methods

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm stuck on an assignment where I'm supposed to use helper methods to sort rows and columns in a 2D int array in Java. It's explicitly required to use two different methods to sort an array. Anyways so here is my code for sorting a row

```
public static void sortOneRow(int[] arr1) {

 int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr1.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] > arr1[j]) {
                temp = arr1[i];
                arr1[i] = arr1[j];
                arr1[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's to sort a column if given an input parameter representing the 2D array and the column index:

```
  public static void sortOneColumn(int[][] x, int colNo) {
    // Sorting one column
    int[] thisCol = new int[x.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        thisCol[i] = x[i][colNo];
    }

    // Sort 

    sortOneRow(thisCol);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i][colNo] = thisCol[i];
    }
```

Now, how do I call these two methods in another method that only takes in the 2D Array and I have to first sort rows then sort columns?

Comment: Why istn't your sortOneRow equivalent to the sortOneColumn one? In both cases it is a 2D array right?

Comment: Cant you use Arrays.sort method as well?

Comment: @Adya no, can't use that

Comment: @JorgeCampos by the instructions I have to create different methods to sort rows and columns then use each of those methods to sort a 2D matrix

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to reuse your own methods to sort an 2D array. Hope this can help:

```
public static void sort(int[][] a){
   if(a == null || a.length == 0) return;

   for(int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
     sortOneRow(a[row]);
   }

   for(int col = 0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
     sortOneColumneRow(a, col);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @samdukez thanks, if so, could you plz kindly accept my answer to mark that your question has been resolved :) thanks

Comment: hey sorry I'm on a new account and I tried to accept the answer but it tells me I need 15 reputation points.